# NodeJS: what is difference between "./.." and ".." in require?

Tags: node.js, path, require

What is difference between

```
var XYZ = require('./../xyz');
```

and

```
var XYZ = require('../xyz');
```

Which one is prefered?

Comment: preference differ from person to person.
i choose the 2nd way!

Answer (score 1):

If we narrate it:

`../` means to say look one directory back while `./../` means to say look one directory back from current directory.

Summray: It's samething.

Answer (score 0):

`'../xyz'` is prefered because both do end up with the same result, but the second one is more clear in its intention.